# Raspberry pi power supply

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am a beginner to this Raspberry Pi board. I wanted to power my board using 5V adaptor. I am currently having phone charger whose output specifications are 5V, 0.7 to 1A. So can I use the same adaptor to power my board?

Comment: Check the voltage with a voltmeter before you connect it. Not all adapters are regulated voltage. If it is unregulated you'll notice a much higher voltage when unloaded.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. According to the [manual](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/260) of the raspberry pi, it needs 700mA max. So if your charger can supply up to 1A you will have no problem with that.

**EDIT:**

As jippie and Andyaka have truly said, the output must be regulated 5V. So take this into account as well.

by the way this is another [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX3kiRUf7mg) might be helpful

Comment: I am using Raspberry Pi B, so i guess my phone charger will be compatible for this.Thanks for the link.

Comment: Anytime. Btw You can accept my answer if you think that's a true answer.

Comment: The charger spec says 5V, 0.7V to 1A. What if the RaPi is only taking 300mA - do you know enough about the charger (based on what the op said in his question) to say you will have "no problem with that"? Do you know what the max input voltage of the RaPi is? Can you say the 5V supply proposed by the OP is regulated and doesn't supply (say) 10V on no-load? Would this cause a problem possibly?